# Interpretation of probability density greater than one

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Good morning to everyone,

I'm trying to figure out how to interpret a probability density greater than one, but I didn't find any explanation that I considered satisfactory... Let me formalize my question.

Suppose that you have a random variable $p$ uniformly distributed over the support $[0,\frac 1 2]$. Obviously, it the probability density of this random variable is $f(p)=2$. Does this mean that if I marginally increase the realization of my random variable, the amount of probability "clustered around that new realization" (I couldn't find a better term to express the concept, I'm thinking about the graph of the cumulative, which has slope $2$ in this case) doubles?.

Sorry if I'm not being clear, I couldn't find better words to express my doubts.

Comment: Not sure I see the question.  Yes, if the density function is $2$, then doubling the region in question will double the probability (under sensible assumptions).  But, of course, this has nothing to do with the density being $>1$.

Comment: Perfect, more than sufficient. I used the $f(p)=2$ example just to make it intuitive, I understand that the interpretation is valid for any value of $f(p)$. Thanks!!

Comment: "Probability is less than one" means something because probability is a pure number. If the random variable $X$ is a dimensioned quantity (say length) then its probability density has dimensions of reciprocal length. E.g., a probability density of $3$ per foot is the same as a probability density of $0.25$ per inch. There is nothing wrong with the probability density having that value at a point or on a short interval; it would be impossible to maintain that probability density over an interval of more than $4$ inches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density function of a continuous random variable is *not* an uncountably infinite 'list' of probabilities.
A continuous random variable has no probability at any one point.

A continuous random variable has positive probabilities only for intervals. (Intervals can be very short, but they cannot shrink of length $0.)$
The density function of a random variable $X$ provides
a way to find probabilities such as $P(0 < X < 0.1).$ By convention, one
writes $P(X = 0.0300)=0,$ and similarly for any other individual value.

**Example 1.** Let $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(-.2, .2),$ with density function $f_X(t) = 2.5,$ for $-.2 \le x \le 2$ and $0$ elsewhere.

The total area under the density curve is $1.$
In order for that to be true, notice that the height of the density function must exceed $1$ for some values of $t.$ (See plot below.)

Then
$$P(0 < X < 0.1) = \int_0^{0.1} f_X(t)\,dt
= \int_0^{0.1} 2.5\, dt = 0.25.$$

Consider the plot below:

```
curve(dunif(x,-.2,.2), -.5,.5, col="blue",
      lwd=2, n=10001, ylab="PDF", xlab="t", 
      main="Density of UNIF(-.2, .2)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = c(0, .1), col="red")
```

The desired probability is the area beneath the
(blue) density curve between the red vertical lines.

[image]

**Example 2.**  Suppose that $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 10, \sigma=0.1),$ with density function $f_Y(t).$ Then
$P(Y \le 9.8) = \int_{-\infty}^{9.8} f_Y(t)\, dt = 0.02275.$

However, the this integral cannot be evaluated
using the ordinary methods of calculus. One must use numerical integration or printed tables (obtained by numerical integration). In R,
one can evaluate this integral using a normal
cumulative distribution function (CDF) `pnorm`, (also obtained by numerical means).

```
pnorm(9.8, 10, .1)
[1] 0.02275013
```

In the figure below, the desired probability is the area under the density curve to the left of
the vertical red line.

[image]

```
curve(dnorm(x, 10,.1), 9.5,10.5, col="blue",
      ylab="PDF", xlab="t", 
      main="Density of NORM(10, .1)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 9.8, col="red")
```

Comment: Thank you Bruce, way too much!